# Sql F# Type Provider, App.Config, and ConnectionStrings?

Tags: sql, f#, type-providers

I am trying to use app.config file to load the connection string into the type provider but I am receiving the following error:

> error FS3033: The type provider `'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'` reported an error: Invalid provider `''` in connection string entry `'Server1'` in config file `'...\app.config'`. `SqlDataConnection` can only be used with provider `'System.Data.SqlClient'`.

I put the connection strings in the app.config file as so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Server1" connectionString="Server=..."/>
    <add name="Server2" connectionString="Server=..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and then reference them in F# as so:

```ml
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName = "Server1", Views = false, Functions = false, StoredProcedures = false>
```

Any thoughts where the issue is?

Comment: Can you post the full connection string from your app.config - you can anonymise the details - I suspect that might not be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `providerName` for the connection string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Server1" connectionString="Server=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Server2" connectionString="Server=..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've adjusted the provided `app.config`, `Server1` functions, `Server2` fails with the message you've reported.